# SQL plural/singular searches

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

How can I make plural/singular words pull all forms?

Example: If a person searches for "mens rings" how can I check the data base to see if any of the fields contain mens, men, men's, ring, rings, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It dosn't seem that using LIKE would be the best approach for what you need.  I would look into MySQL FULLTEXT indexing to get the basic functionality working.  I'll have to look into the plural thing a bit more to see if that can be accomplished.

Take a look at these two links for FULLTEXT indexing info.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-search.html
- http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Here is a snippet from the second article:

```
SELECT headline, story FROM news
WHERE MATCH (headline,story) AGAINST ('Hurricane');
```

**UPDATE:**

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430690/define-mysql-indexing) in which a comment seems to suggest that the FULLTEXT indexing will take plural and grammatical forms into account but he dosn't cite a source, so it's hard for me to say for sure.  Can you try the FULLTEXT indexing method?

Answer (score 3):

The [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) `full-text` search engine for MySQL handles such cases, and a few more (see [here](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=302)).

It uses the **Porter Stemmer algorithm** [[2]](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/)[[3]](http://maya.cs.depaul.edu/classes/ds575/porter.html) to map things like "fishing", "fished", "fish", and "fisher" to a root stem of "fish" (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from index_table where item_name rlike '[[:<:]]preform[s]*[es]*[ies]*[[:>:]]';
```

Check if this helps. My case it worked out. Although will not cover for all plurals but yes for 90-95% cases.

Cheers,
Ashish