# best way to search data-base table for user input keywords?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, search

I want to build a product-search engine.

I was thinking of using google-site-search but that really searches Google's index of your site. I do not want to search that. I want to search a specific table (all the fields, even ones the user never sees) on my data-base for given keywords.

But I want this search to be as robust as possible, I was wondering if there was something already out there I could use? if not whats the best way to go about making it myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) `full-text search` for MySQL.

Here's also a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/) from IBM using PHP.

Comment: Sphinx is really fast on both ends (indexing and searching). Definitely worth looking into.

Comment: Not to mention `Sphinx` would also solve your other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088433/sql-plural-singular-searches

Comment: Thanks, I tried to install sphinx, but I guess I am too novice a linux user to know what I am doing, just about every other step gave me some error that I had no clue what it meant or what to do.

Comment: Tutorials: http://acidborg.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/how-to-install-and-configure-sphinx-in-ubuntu-9-10-with-mysql-support/ http://pkarl.com/articles/guide-django-full-text-search-sphinx-and-django-sp/

Comment: Thanks, i'll try my best to figure it out now, if not i'll come back to it once I get a little more linux experience under my belt.

Answer (score 2):

I'd focus on MySQL Full-Text search first.  Take a look at these links:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-search.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Here is a snippet from the first link:

> Full-text searching is performed using
>   MATCH() ... AGAINST syntax. **MATCH()
>   takes a comma-separated list that
>   names the columns to be searched**.
>   **AGAINST takes a string to search for,
>   and an optional modifier that
>   indicates what type of search to
>   perform**. The search string must be a
>   literal string, not a variable or a
>   column name. There are three types of
>   full-text searches:

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll use this if I can't figure out sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

As far as stuff that's already out there, take a look at these :

- [Search all tables](http://www.users.drew.edu/skass/sql/SearchAllTables.sql.txt) (for SQL Server, but you could probably adapt it to MySQL)
- [Another search all tables](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm) (for SQL Server, but you could probably adapt it to MySQL)
- [Search all varchar columns in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834912/sql-search-for-a-string-in-every-varchar-column-in-a-database)
- [MySQL Full-Text Search](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000576.html)
- [Using MySQL Full-Text Search](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE value REGEXP 'searchterm'

Allows you to use many familiar search tricks such as +, "", etc

This is a native function of MySQL.  No need to use go to a new language or plugin which might be faster, but is also extra time for maintenance, troubleshooting, etc.

It may be a little slower than doing some crazy C++ based mashup, but users don't generally notice a difference between milliseconds......

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might also want to look into (if you're not going to utilize sphinx), is [stemming your keywords](http://pecl.php.net/package/stem). It will make matching keywords a bit easier (as stemming 'cheese' and 'cheesy' would end up producing the same stemmed word) which makes your keyword matching a bit more flexible.