# Php mysql search - Search not working if with plural and singular

Tags: php, mysql, search, singular, plural

If I search "sales order" it's fetching "sales order" and "sales order**s**" in results. It's fetching the result with "s" also.

But if I search "sales orders" it's fetching "sales orders" only but I want "sales order" will also fetch.

I am using php mysql query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_posts as p 
    inner join wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID 
    where (p.post_type = 'abc' or p.post_type = 'xyz') 
    and p.post_title LIKE '%sales order%' 
    or (pm.meta_key = 'xyzkeyword' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sales order%') 
    GROUP by p.ID 
    ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Comment: [hope this thread helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088433/sql-plural-singular-searches)

Comment: your query is right but your question is not sure what you want to achieve. if you are using like and if you search by 'sales order' with like you will get both

Comment: read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with this without "%"

```
p.post_title LIKE 'sales order'
```

Comment: then what is the purpose of like operator here?

Comment: @ravi patel - I don't want exact search. Search will be with like operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this

```
and (p.post_title LIKE '%sales order%'  OR p.post_title LIKE '%sales orders%' )
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure about this query but you can check as

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_posts as p 
inner join wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID 
where (p.post_type = 'abc' or p.post_type = 'xyz') 
and p.post_title LIKE '%sales%' AND  p.post_title LIKE '%order%'
or (pm.meta_key = 'xyzkeyword' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sales order%') 
GROUP by p.ID 
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_posts as p 
inner join wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID 
where (p.post_type = 'abc' or p.post_type = 'xyz') 
and p.post_title LIKE '%sales%order%'
or (pm.meta_key = 'xyzkeyword' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sales order%') 
GROUP by p.ID 
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use MySQL Full text search,check if FULLTEXT indexes are there

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_posts as p 
    inner join wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID 
    where (p.post_type = 'abc' or p.post_type = 'xyz')
    match (p.post_title) against ('sales order')
    or (pm.meta_key = 'xyzkeyword' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sales order%') 
    GROUP by p.ID 
    ORDER BY p.id DESC
```